# I am trying to display a view to see multiple units of measure for a set of data I have in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have to generate a report from a SQL query.

The report contains trade data in a certain unit of measure, the users want to be able to see the data in three different units of measure.

Is there a way of adding a parameter where you can to pick a unit of measure and then it will convert the data into that specified unit of measure and not filter for the unit of measure?

For example I have the following trade detail
ID = 1
Amount = 100 MWH

I want to be able to change the parameters to allow me to see that amount in THERMS and KWH, I have the conversion factors it's just being able to choose between the three is the difficult part .

Comment: Sounds like a case for `case`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a float parameter.

On the label enter the unit names and on the values set the modifiers based on the main unit.

The main unit will have modifier = 1

[image]

Your value expression will be like `=Parameters!UnitModifier.Value * Fields!val.Value`

[image]

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much, also one last thing I wanted to have different decimal places for each unit. Is there any thing I can do about it?

Comment: You can use an Iif or Switch expression on the value textboxes format property to return a format string based on parameter selection.

Comment: Could you show a visual example like you've done with the above?